# Ошибка в HttpClient

Tags: android

Есть самый простой HttpClient

```
    public class HttpClient
{
    Context ctx;
    AntoninHttpClient httpClient;
    public HttpClient(Context c){
        this.ctx=c;
    }

    public void get(String url,AntoninHttpClient a){
        this.httpClient = a;
        MyTask m = new MyTask();
        m.execute(url);

    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String resultJson = "0";
            try {

                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                resultJson = buffer.toString();
                return resultJson;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result!=null){
                httpClient.onData(result);}else{
                httpClient.onError("not");
            }

        }
    }

    public interface AntoninHttpClient {
        public void onData(String data);
        public void onError(String error);

    }

}
```

Если отправить запрос например на `https://api.vk.com/method/users.get.xml?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&v=5.53` все нормально, приходит ответ, но если я отправляю запрос на http://***.16mb.com/login.php(это мой сайт на бесплатном хостинге, там я тестирую приложение) выбивает ошибку(приложение закрывается). В чем может быть проблемма?

```
 login.php
<?php
echo "Test";
?>
```

Это последняя запись в логах

```
08-03 14:10:44.690 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 479K, 23% free 2995K/3872K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at com.example.antonin.feeling.core.HttpClient$MyTask.doInBackground(HttpClient.java:40)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at com.example.antonin.feeling.core.HttpClient$MyTask.doInBackground(HttpClient.java:24)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-03 14:10:44.700 7087-7671/com.example.antonin.feeling W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Стактрейс ошибки в студию. На кофейной гуще не гадаем.

Comment: Сори, не тот лог, теперь с ошибкой

Comment: Судя по ошибка у вас не может кастонуться HttpsURLConnection из Java к HttpsURLConnection из OkHttp

Comment: заменил HttpsURLConnection на HttpURLConnection вроде работает